# Load User control with Query string

Tags: asp.net

My requirement is like i need to load a n number of user controls using asp Repeater.

```
List<string> userControlList = new List<string>();
userControlList.Add("~/WebUserControl2.ascx");
userControlList.Add("~/WebUserControl.ascx");
Repeater1.DataSource = userControlList;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And in the ItemDataBound, I am loading the user control using Page.LoadControl.

```
string userControlLink = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();
e.Item.FindControl("ItemPanel").Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(userControlLink));
```

Here, I need to send parameters to some user control by which the control will be loaded.
I am not able to use properties because i can't type cast it at run time.

Is there any other way by which i can send some parameters to user control?
I tried with query string, but it resulted in run time exception.

Comment: This is not the prettiest solution, but you could set these values to some hidden fields and recover at the ASCX.

Comment: Check this link. http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/03/23/73096.aspx